# ggplot2 facet grid barplots get stacked when I try to change x-axis, cannot unstack

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet-grid

I created a barplot looking as follows:
[image]

using

```
ggplot(Halle1, aes(x=regime, y=CO_real,
                    fill = hight)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        facet_grid(~ Gang, scales = "free_x", space= "free_x", 
                    labeller=labeller(Gang = Halle1_labels) )
```

and I would like the x-axis to show subgroups, where the labels are either "hinten" or "vorne" based on the second last letter ("h"/"v") of regime. My dataframe already contains a column named "location" that is either "hinten" or "vorne".

However when I try to plot that using

```
ggplot(Halle1, aes(x=location, y=CO_real,
                    fill = hight)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        facet_grid(~ Gang, scales = "free_x", space= "free_x", 
                    labeller=labeller(Gang = Halle1_labels) )
```

my bars get stacked:
[image]

I tried to unstack them using the `position="dodge"` in `geom_bar()` but than it looks like this:
[image]

What happened here? And how can I solve it while keeping the x-axis since that is as I'd like it to be?

Edit: The data looks somewhat like this:

```
Halle1 <- data.frame(
  regime = structure(c(2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 3L), levels = c("H1M7ho", "H1M7hu", "H1M3ho", "H1M3hu", "H1M4vo", "H1M4vu", "H1M1ho", "H1M1hu", "H1M2vo", "H1M2vu"), class = "factor"),
  CO_real = c(27, 34, 29, 23, 25, 28, 31, 30), 
  Gang = c(41, 41, 44, 44, 41, 44, 52, 44),
  location = c("hinten", "hinten", "hinten", "vorne", "hinten", "vorne", "hinten", "hinten"),
  hight = c("unten", "unten", "unten", "oben", "oben", "unten", "unten", "oben")
)
```

Comment: Can you also provide the data?  Or some fake data that reproduce your example?

Comment: By default `geom_bar` or `geom_col` will give you a stacked bar chart. When you map regime on x, you have only one value, hence there is nothing to stack. Switching to location you now have two values and get a stacked barchart. Hence, using position = "dodge" is the way to go. Unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce your second issue (i.e. the equal sized bars) using your code and data.